# Alien comes to Earth. When man learns it came to save humanity, man allows alien to die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the title of a short story that I read a while back.

**Plot**:

There is a fish-like alien that came to Earth. A man (we'll call them Person A) finds it and gives it water so that it does not die. The alien asks for books and newspapers so that it can learn about the world. The alien eventually tells Person A that it came to Earth in order to prevent humanity's destruction.

The story ends with the narrator learning that Person A took away the alien's water source after learning of its intentions, thus allowing it to die. The narrator and some of his peers reflect upon how Person A's traditionalism and lack of curiosity may be the cause of humanity's doom.

**Other details**:

I read an English-translated version in 2016, though I believe the story itself is older. Originally written in Spanish.

Comment: Holy crap, that's grim!

Comment: Sounds interesting though, I hope we find an answer for you!